# When (if ever) to use plural form of Homo sapiens?

Tags: latin

Which should I say?

> These are two fine *Homo sapiens*.

or

> These are two fine *Homines sapientes*.

(Assume I insist on using the Latin *Homo sapiens* in my sentence, for whatever reason. Edit to elaborate: For example, for ironic effect or humor or as one suggests, to demonstrate my erudition.)

There's a brief discussion of this matter [here](http://grammarist.com/usage/homo-sapiens/).

Comment: If you insist on using the Latin _Homo sapiens_, you'll be off-topic here. If you recognise that _Homo sapiens_ is a scientifically accepted binomial, you'll fit in with the way scientists use the term: two examples of Homo sapiens and six of Gorilla gorilla gorilla.

Comment: Using the Latin plural might be stylistically justified in some non-academic contexts (e.g. to demonstrate your erudition in a blog post).

Answer (score 4):

You should say:

> These are two fine examples of Homo sapiens.

Comment: Remark: "Examples" in this context is acting as a [measure word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_word).

Answer (score 4):

Never. If you really want to use *Homo sapiens*, you should say

> One *Homo sapiens* 
>   Two *Homo sapiens* 
>   Three *Homo sapiens* 
>   Four *Homo sapiens* 
>   Too many *Homo sapiens*

This is the same for all species names. For example, you would say *five Mus musculus* or *six Tribolium castaneum*. As a general rule though, you just wouldn't. Even in scientific literature, you will tend to refer to the species by their common names, so *four humans*, *five mice*, *six red flour beetles*.